# How to pack commits in git

Tags: git, github

I have two branches branchA and branchB. On branchA, I committed several times. Now I want to pack all commits on branchA from sometime and apply to branchB.

### Update

To my understanding, `merge` will apply all commits in branchA to branchB, but I just want to pack some commits, say the latest five commits in branchA.

And I also know that I can use `cherry-pick` to migrate commit one by one, but I'd like to pack them.

Comment: The term "pack" has a very specific meaning in the `git` world, which is quite at odds with what I think you are trying to ask here. I would suggest rewording your question to avoid using that term in such a foreign manner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cherry-pick` the commits you need from `branchA` to `branchB`:

First get the commit IDs you want to "pack", you can get this by simply doing:

```
(on branchA)
git log
```

Then switch back to `branchB` and cherry-pick the commits, preferentially in chronological order:

```
(on branchB)
git cherry-pick <commitID>
```

In addition to your latest comment and @twalberg's suggestion if you want to do this in one go for multiple commits you can do so

```
(on branchB)
git cherry-pick <commitA> <commitB> <commitB>
```

Merit to @twalberg on this last bit.

Comment: Please do squash merge.

Comment: that was my original answer  , but the OP asks just for some of the commits.

Comment: thanks @bitoiu. According to your answer, I have to migrate the commit one by one. But I'd like to know how to pack.

Comment: @bitoiu Confused by your comment about only being able to "pack" commits if they are in a range (partially because "pack" has a completely different meaning with `git`). Are you aware that you can `git cherry-pick A  C D F H` as well as `git cherry-pick A..E` and so on...

Comment: Hi @twalberg, what you say makes a lot of sense. I went to look for an option with `git-format-patch` because I did not know you could use multiple non-sequential ids on a `cherry-pick`. I'll update with mention.